# Do Nginx Proxies automatically forward the Authorization Header

Tags: http, nginx, jwt, openid-connect

Or do we need something like `proxy_pass_header Authorization` in the proxy configuration?  The end goal would be to ensure that api endpoints get the JWT token.

Comment: `Authorization` is a request header. `proxy_pass_header` operates on response headers. Check if you are disabling the header with `proxy_pass_request_headers` or `proxy_set_header`.

Comment: So in general, barring that we did not somehow muck up the configuration,  nginx should pass the Authorization without any further assistance right?  It's usually the default for most proxies, just want to make sure I understand it right for Nginx?

Comment: Yes. And I have confirmed that on my test server.